# EXCEL VBA - declaring range when the sheet name is a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I use this line of code:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).ListObjects(sName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=
    Range ("sName.Name[[#All],[Keyword]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Now, this line is a part of a longer function that supposed to do the same thing for a wider list of sheets. Therefore, I need to change the range selection:

```
  Range ("sName.Name[[#All],[Keyword]]")
```

To be based on a variable, I just can't find the right solution on how to do it.
** I tried a few options, improvised, didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

That is the full code btw:

```
Sub Filter()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call Filtering("US")                  'To prepare Data for All Keywords
    MsgBox "Updated"
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function Filtering(sName As String)
'
' Filtering Macro
'

'
    Sheets(sName).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).ListObjects(sName).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).ListObjects(sName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=
        Range ("sName.Name[[#All],[Keyword]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).ListObjects(sName).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).ListObjects(sName).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).ListObjects(sName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("sName.Name[[#All],[Position]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal _

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).ListObjects(sName).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(sName).Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<=20" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
End Function
```

Comment: The problem is you are setting you are referencing a **Named Range** called _sName.Name[[#All],[Position]]_.  What are you trying to sort with the sheet? Could you provide a snap shot picuture of the Sheet "US" and with data and provide a description of what the code is trying to achieve.

Comment: add the sheet names into an array and loop through

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this task is fairly simple. First, I would like to point out (largely for future coders with similar issues) that the method you are trying to call needs a string argument and you are close.

```
' String argument, but "sName" is never interpreted. It is taken literally.
Range ("sName[[#All],[Keyword]]")

' Returns the string representation of sName and concatenates it into
' the rest of the string argument. If sName was Foo', this would read as:
' Range ("Foo[[#All],[Keyword]]")
Range (sName & "[[#All],[Keyword]]")
```

Now, to make a larger observation on your code I would strongly suggest you find resources on improving the code overall. References to 'ActiveWorkbook' can be risky, and you are bound to get run-time errors. 'Select' statements create the same risk. I know you are likely learning through the macro recorder (as we all did), but make sure you learn how to avoid Select and Activate before you actually release that project.

Comment: Ayyyy I knew it's something with the string, but I didn't know how to pull it off, thanks man!